# How can i export a blob container entry in Azure to a SQL Server using PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I have successfully moved a `.bacpac` file (a copy of my Azure SQL database) to a container using the following:

```
azcopy copy "C:\testdbs\TestDB.bacpac" "https://account.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1/?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bjqt&srt=sco&sp=rwddgcup&se=2019-05-01T05:01:17Z&st=2019-04-30T21:01:17Z&spr=https&sig=MGCXiyEzbtttkr3ewJIh2AR8KrghSy1DGM9ovN734bQF4%3D"
```

I can browse the Azure Portal and see the `.bacpac` file there.

Now I want to be able to create a SQL Server database on a SQL Server sitting in a resource group.

The storage account and the SQL server are on different subscriptions , not sure if that matters

How can I do this using PowerShell? I don't want any user interaction

Comment: Your question requires a lot more details to obtain a quality answer. Start with reading this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: question has been updated

Comment: Write the PowerShell scripts. There are lots of examples available. Once you have a problem with your code, post a question.